# How to change retrieved records from db in model before delivering it in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1

How could I perform some modification on all data asked of a model before it returns it? The callbacks in rails appear to only deal with creation or updating of data, not retreival.

I bet this is probably a very obvious solution I'm not seeing.

Here's an example:

I have a table called `quotes`. Before any data is given by the `Quote` model, I'd like to replace all occurances of the word `Sun Tzu` with `Chinese Dude`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think of this a different way.

You want to change quote.text, so it returns the database value of text with the substitution applied.

Here's the code

```
def text
  if self[:text]
    self[:text].gsub(/Sun Tzu/, "Chinese Dude")
  end
end
```

Thereby you only overwrite what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a callback which can help you:

The **after_initialize** is triggered after new objects are instantiated.

[Here's](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html) how to use **after_initialize**

Comment: I read that but there is no mention on how to loop though returned objects (the example shown appears to only work with a single instance). -- i.e. how to loop through self.* results?

Comment: This callback triggers on every object that you're retrieving from db, so kinda i didn't understand what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Use [after_find](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html). I don't believe it works the same way as other callbacks so you have to manually define the method instead of doing `after_find :my_method`. So do it like this

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  def after_find
    # do stuff here
  end
end
```